# Papa Parse: copy an array from .csv to my code

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm using papa parse to read a large .csv and copy it's contents to an array in my code. If I execute the code below the console shows the second log first, as an empty array. I would have expected it to be filled with the contents of the .csv by calling the function parseMe, before it would be logged again?

```
function parseMe(url, callBack){
    Papa.parse(url, {
        complete: function(results) {
        callBack(results.data[0]);
        }
    });
}

function doStuff(data){
    newArray=data;
    console.log(newArray); //log no. 1
}

var newArray=[];
parseMe(document.getElementById("file").files[0], doStuff);
console.log(newArray); //log no. 2
```

Comment: What is the question you want answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your "log no. 2" shows an empty result array is that the array has not yet been parsed when that line of code runs.  If you add some identifying text to your log output you'll see something like this:

```
(Log no.2) After parse call but before complete fired, newArray: []

(Log no.1) In OnComplete callback, Array is: [ populated_array ]
```

That is, the order of execution is as follows:

1. Papa parse starts parsing the input file
2. Log no. 2 outputs, showing an empty result array
3. Papa parse finishes parsing the input file
4. The on complete callback fires
5. Log no. 1 outputs, showing a populated result array

Working Pen: http://codepen.io/sensei/pen/mPPKBP/

The key concept here is Asynchronous Execution; I recommend reading up on JavaScript Promises ([blogpost](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)) for a modern API that will help you grok the web application implementation of this key computing concept.